# The page doesn't refresh until MutationObserver callback function execute thoroughly, takes a long time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension using JavaScript for a website. When the user click on the 'More results' button, more results are displayed on the screen. I used the `MutationObserver` to listen on the website DOM change and made some modification. Here is the code.

```
var mo=new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
            mutations.forEach(mo_callback)
        })
mo.observe(document,{childList:true})

function mo_callback(mutation){
//first step, run quickly
//second step, make a request to an API, time wasting, need 5 secs or more
}
```

The code can work but the user's experience is bad. Since the second step took a long time, the result didn't show until `mo_callback` finished. Before loading my extension, the user can get the result displayed in 1 sec after clicking on "More results" button, but it takes 5 secs or more after loading my extension. I have tried to use `async function`for the second step, but since the second step is included in the `mo_callback`as a whole, it doesn't work.

I hope the result can display on the screen immediately or after the first step of `mo_callback`. How to solve it?

Appreciate your help

Comment: If `mutations` has 10,000 items your code will run `mo_callback` 10,000 times. Depending on how you use mutation records, maybe you can simply run `mo_callback()` or use *debounce*.

Comment: Only one element present in the mutations. Evey time the user click on the "More result button", only one element change. It is ```mo_callback``` time consuming

Comment: I solved. I miss set ```async : false``` in ```$.ajax```function and now it works as I hope